# Proper way of creating game objects classes in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I was just wondering, if you want to create an object for a game, lets say a ball,

Should you create a class called ball that it contains the sprite and the body?, like:

```
 public class Ball {

   BaseGameActivity mActivity;
   Sprite s;
   Body mBody
      public Ball(TextureRegion texture,BaseGameActivity mActivity){
          this.mActivity=mActivity;
          s= new Sprite (0,0,texture,mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
          mBody=PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mActivity.mWorld,s, BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody,PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,0,2));

          //then it shoud be properly attached to scene and world etc...

      }
  }
```

A class that extends sprite? like:

```
 public class Ball extends Sprite {

   BaseGameActivity mActivity;
   Body mBody
      public Ball(TextureRegion texture,BaseGameActivity mActivity){
          super (0,0,texture,mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
          this.mActivity=mActivity;
          mBody=PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mActivity.mWorld,this, BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody,PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,0,2));

          //then it shoud be properly attached to scene and world etc...

      }
  }
```

Or another way?

Which is the fastest? Which is the easier? Or the way doesn't matter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just do like this.. u will probably need other sprites and other stuff...

```
public class Ball extends BaseGameActivity{

//constructor and other methods

BitmapTextureAtlas ballAtlas;

ITextureRegion ballTexture;

//in onLoadResources load ur atlas

//create texture region

//then in onCreateScene create a scene

//simply attach ur sprite ball to ur scene

}
```

you can create sprites anywhere.. you are not bound to create separate class for that

Comment: name ur class MainActivity or Ball...depends upon you

Comment: I know you can do it on the activity, but when you want to use it in multiple activities, and the "ball" has some properties like  `.bounce()` or `.fadeSlowly()` it comes handy to create classes instead of making it on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use both approach, it depends on you and your coding style / application infrastructure. :)

Altough I use a generic SceneManager class with a reference to the activity, instead of multiple activities